# Message: Undefined property: User::$view_data with Codeigniter trying to build a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to build a simple controller for a registration form as seen on a Youtube video, but for some reason, I'm getting an error with a piece of code that works for him.

```
<?php

class User extends CI_Controller {

function __User() {

    parent::CI_Controller();

    $this->view_data['base_url'] = base_url();
}

function index() {

    $this->register();
}

function register() {

    $this->load->view('view_register', $this->view_data);
}

}
```

That's what I currently have, with:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

set in autoload.php.

I've tried to search around for answers to this question, but nothing appears to work and the only solution I've seen was for a slightly different problem. Does anyone have any idea as to what could be wrong?

Also, if it helps any, this is the exact error message:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: User::$view_data

Filename: controllers/user.php

Line Number: 19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they are trying to reference a field called `view_data`. Adding this would fix it:

```
class User extends CI_Controller
{
    private $view_data = array();
}
```

Comment: I honestly cannot thank you enough for that answer. It's working perfectly now and I can finally get back to work!